# Show Django Admin views in my App

Tags: django

I am creating a website and I want to bring some of the functionality from django admin to my app. Something like adding users and group should be something anyone can do from my app. They don't have to go to www.website.com/admin/ to do that. I also have written some other functionality in admin which can be useful for general user.

Please advise.
Thanks.
Have a great day.

Comment: You can start with this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you want. If you need a different look of the admin, use custom templates, if you want different URIs(URLs) you could user redirect from going from the new URI to admin URI. But you still need to create the UI for your users outside the admin. Using Django Rest Framework for creating rest APIs and something in the front end like AngujarJS or ReactJS, etc.

Comment: Thanks Edilio. I think I got it.

Comment: It will help me and others if you accept my answer as the valid one